# I need find 1 simple rootkit to test chkrootkit in centos?

Tags: security, testing, chkrootkit

I want to find 1 simple rootkit to test `chkrootkit` (a tool used to detect rootkit). Please recommend to me 1 rootkit and show me how to set it up or install it.

Comment: You might be better off looking for a sample testfile,
such as is used for virus-scanners:

    http://www.eicar.org/83-0-Anti-Malware-Testfile.html

Answer (score 1):

I found these via google:

#### Windows

- [ZeroAccess / Sirefef Rootkit - 5 fresh samples](http://contagiodump.blogspot.com/2012/12/zeroaccess-sirefef-rootkit-5-fresh.html)

*payloads*

- [Download the 5 files below plus the file dumped from memory](http://www.mediafire.com/?9n85ecfvy47g2xz)
- [Download 2 pcap files from 2 runs of A2611095F689FADFFD3068E0D4E3E7ED](http://www.mediafire.com/?1ff8oqu4cl989uy)

*excerpt*

> ZeroAccess rootkit is far from new and exciting but but this is a fresh lot with still active C2 servers.
>
> Although the dropper is detected by at least half of AV engines, post infection detection is another story. I tried Kaspersky TDSS Killer, Avast Rootkit utility and RootRepeal without any success. I used Gmer and LordPE to carve out the hidden file from the memory. You can use Redline or Volatility too.
>
> You can download 5 files below together with pcaps from one of the files and the file dumped from memory. It appears that free videos and apps names are used as the lure in this case.

#### Linux

- [Dec 2012 Linux.Chapro - trojan Apache iframer](http://contagiodump.blogspot.com/2012/12/dec-2012-linuxchapro-trojan-apache.html)

*payload*

- [Download](http://www.mediafire.com/?i5z41ym006d1t8r)

*excerpt*

```
Here is another notable development of 2012 - Linux malware (see Wirenet trojan posted earlier too)
Research: ESET Malicious Apache module used for content injection: Linux/Chapro.A
All the samples are below. I did not test it thus no pcaps this time.
------Linux/Chapro.A  e022de72cce8129bd5ac8a0675996318
------Injected iframe    111e3e0bf96b6ebda0aeffdb444bcf8d
------Java exploit         2bd88b0f267e5aa5ec00d1452a63d9dc
------Zeus binary         3840a6506d9d5c2443687d1cf07e25d0
```

#### Other samples?

You can search the website [Cantagio](http://contagiodump.blogspot.com/) which is a blog that is maintained for the collection of malware & virus samples.

Comment: maybe this rootkit is used in windows. I need the one in linux :(